# Need a python script to accept a string and number n from user and display n repetition of string using overloading operator

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Need a python script python to accept a string and number n from user and display n repetition of strings by overloading * operator.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is not a code-writing service or a search engine. Please take the [tour], learn [ask], and how to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

This is already built into python.

```
s = "asdf"
n = 10
print(s * n)
```

output:

```
asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
```

Comment: Yes, indeeed. Thank you.

Comment: I want to accept string and the number of repititon from the user.

Comment: Then you can use input. [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) is the documentation: